# hashtable communication with linked list and book class

Tags: c++, data-structures, hash, header

My HashTable class won't recognize stuff from my Book and Linked List class class. I included the header files at the top so I think the problem is in my code?

Did I create the array of linked lists properly? I have a Node struct that creates elements in the linked lists.

Here is my source code for the HashTable Class

```
#include "HashTable.h"
#include "Book.h"
#include "List.h"

using namespace std;

HashTable::HashTable() //constructor
{

    List<Book> Table[SIZE];

    Node *Table[SIZE];


    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        {
            Table[i]= new Node;
            Table[i]->title = "empty";
            Table[i]->author="empty";
            Table[i]->price=-1;
            Table[i]->isbn=0;
            Table[i]->linkprevious=NULL;
            Table[i]->linknext=NULL;
        }

}


int HashTable:: hash(string key) const
{
    int index, sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
            sum += (int) key[i]; //summing the ASCII values for each character in the string
        index = sum % SIZE; //dividing the summed ASCII values by 35 && storing remainder as my index
        return index;

}


void HashTable:: insert(Book b)
{
    int index=hash(b.title);

    if(HashTable[index]->title=="empty") //if array element is empty
    {
        Table->name=b.title;
        Table->author=b.author;
        Table->price=b.price;
        Table->isbn=b.isbn;
    }
    else //if array element is take-->make linked list
    {
        Node *ptr = Table[index]; //points at desired index(that hash determined)
        Node *N = new Node;  //allocate space and fill fields with entered data
        N->title=b.title;
        N->author=b.author;
        N->price=b.price;
        N->isbn=b.isbn;
        while(ptr->linknext!=NULL)//traverse ptr to end of linked list
            //(incase there is already a linked list in given index)
        {
            ptr=ptr->linknext;
        }
        ptr->linknext=N;
    }


}
```

Comment: Time is money for us as it is for you. please just put piece of code which point your problem and no more. Also make it easier and more compact as far as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor uses the same variable (Table) name twice.

```
HashTable::HashTable() //constructor
{
    List<Book> Table[SIZE];
    Node* Table[SIZE];
```

I'm not sure what you are thinking of - perhaps something like:

```
List<Book> Table[SIZE];

for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    Book* book = Table[i].getFirstNode();
    book->title = "empty";
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried copying and pasting the Node struct into my HashTable class  and it still didn't work

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do.  I would think that you create the array of link lists with the size of your mod (35?) and then have a insert method that adds a book to the list using the proper index in the array based on the hash function.  In the constructor of the hash table, don't create any new nodes, set up the previouslink and nextlink to be null in the constructor of the list.